# I can't generate SHA-1 code when I run gradew signingReport

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

Am trying to generate SHA-1 to put in firebase so I can enable google sign-in in my flutter app, but when I run gradew signingReport, the terminal throws an error that

```
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 65

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

What could be the cause

Comment: Class file version 65 means you have some Java code that was compiled for Java 21 and you are using an older Java version to execute it (which doesn't work). But Android Gradle projects are usually not executed using Java 21 (AFAIK gradle is not yet compatible with Java 21). Your posted output already contains the necessary commands to investigate the problem deeper for finding the problem source.

Answer (score 2):

very simple just open the terminal and type the command in the terminal `cd android`.  then run this command `./gradlew signingReport` you will get SHA-1 key and others

Comment: That is what I typed in to get that error

Comment: restart the project using Invalidate catches... then try it

Answer (score 0):

go to "android" directory in android studio in terminal

1. cd android
2. ./gradlew signingReport

this should work. if not try this:

gradlew signingReport